# Get the database backup/dump with EclipseLink

Tags: java, eclipselink, entitymanager, dropwizard

Is there a way of creating the Database Dump / Backup through EclipseLink entity manager? 
I want to add a functionality to my java (dropwizard) project that allows the administrator to download the current database (and perhaps import a new one in). 
I am using H2 Database.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question (at theoretical level at least). I'm not sure is possible, but tell me if anybody has solution. I think best is to think "export all entities from database to some archive"

Comment: 2. most databases (but not all) can be backed up via sql command, so maybe can pass command via JPA raw SQL interface. This has nothing to do with JPA definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fairly easy for you to do, however I don't think the EntityManager does that

(This is not 100 % true - but I could not work out how, so I am presenting you the straight forward alternative that you can use with the EM as well)

So requisites:

You need to have the H2DB and you need to bind your datasource (or unwrap a connection from your entity manager). Then the command you want to run is:

```
SCRIPT TO '/path/to/my/file'
```

So for example, this is how I implemented it:

```
    @Inject
    private DataSource ds;

    @GET
    @Path("dump")
    public Response dump() {


        try (Connection c = ds.getConnection(); Statement s = c.createStatement()) {

            s.execute("SCRIPT TO '/home/artur/tmp/test/test.sql'");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

So, a few points:

You don't need to access the datasource directly. A quick google revealed that eclipselink will give you access to your connection like this:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
...
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Alternatively, this will also work (And does not use any connection/jdbc attributes):

```
emp.get().createNativeQuery("SCRIPT TO '/home/artur/tmp/test/test.sql'").getResultList();
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but you could:

- Pass the filename into the resource so your DBA knows where the dump is created?
- Write to a temp location, read the dump and return a stream (for download)

I don't think that you can get h2db to return the dump for you. However I might be wrong.

**EDIT: I am wrong**

The entityManager method will return a result list with the entire SQL dump. So you have it in the code and in a file (you could remove your file).

Just try it and see what the debugger spits out. Like I said, I am not using EclipseLink so the behaviour might be slightly different.

Have fun, I hope that solves your question :)

Artur